# Magento 2 How to get currency code on basis of GeoIP Country

Tags: magento2, currency

Programatically how to get currency code on basis of GeoIP Country?

Example: Singapore - SGD

Comment: Have you got country based on geoip?

Comment: No still not. Awaiting response.

Comment: Hi, did you got any solution?